# When I change my branch (on Eclipse), my partner's configuration changes too. Which configuration it involves?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, github-for-windows

I'm having a problem in GitHub desktop. I guess this is easy to solve.
When I change my branch (on Eclipse), my partner's configuration of branch changes too.
I think that is because we are using the same config file, but we are not finding it.

Could someone please help us.

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is `change my branch` and what configuration are you talking about?

Comment: Tim, thank you at first time.
Well, when I right click on repository's name (on Eclipse), then I select: [Team] > [Switch To] > [Some branch]. It changes all the others users of GitHub branchs configuration. It means when I change from a branch to another in my Eclipse, it changes on all the others whose is using the same GitHub repository, changes the branch on Eclipse.

Comment: After you do that it immediately changes for him, too? Are you committing anything before it happens maybe?

Comment: Yes, it changes immediately. But not, it happens even without commit anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were making all wrong.

We were linking the same central repository instead of each one create a clone of it in one's computer.

As we were linking the same folder, we were accessing the same config file, this was causing the problem.

It was a great conceptual mistake about how to use GitHub.

Thank you a lot.

Sorry about that.